# optional url part rewriterule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to find out how can I write rewriterule in htaccess with an optional part. Normally I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([A-Za-z\-]+)/([A-Za-z\-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\-([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ /system.php?lang=$1&category=$2&subcategory=$3&year=$4&month=$5&id=$6&title=$7 [QSA,L]
```

It works fine if I have address e.g.

```
http://dev.example.com/en/blog/usa/2013/9/1-title-of-post
```

The result is:

```
$_GET["lang"]="en"; 
$_GET["category"]="blog";
$_GET["subcategory"]="usa";
$_GET["year"]=2013;
$_GET["month"]=9;
$_GET["id"]=1;
$_GET["title"]="title-of-post";
```

But sometimes I just want to use address like:

```
http://dev.example.com/en/about/me
```

And I want this: (I mean not define other values, but server find that address)

```
$_GET["lang"]="en"; 
$_GET["category"]="about";
$_GET["subcategory"]="me";
$_GET["year"]=null;
$_GET["month"]=null;
$_GET["id"]=null;
$_GET["title"]=null;
```

So I want optional part starting with year, but if someone writes address with year and other statements I want to take it.

Thank you for yout help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? It's not clear at all. Under what criteria do you want it to match, and under what criteria do you want it to not match? Do you want it to have exactly three slash-separated parts after the domain name, optionally followed by a date consisting of three slash-separated numbers, and only in those cases some additional stuff separated from the date by a hyphen? I'm inferring this from the regex, the description doesn't say much about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh, also, does the first part necessarily have to be lowercase, while capitals are allowed otherwise? That's what the regex seems to be requiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the new information, I think I understand what you're trying to do. I believe this will work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([A-Za-z\-]+)/([A-Za-z\-]+)(/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9\-]+))?$ /system.php?lang=$1&category=$2&subcategory=$3&year=$5&month=$6&id=$7&title=$8 [QSA,L]
```

Note the changed numbers in the match variables (**$1**, etc.). You need one throwaway match group to make the second part optional, so the numbering skips one. Year is now **$5**, and everything after that shifts by 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for my weak specification. I added values what i expectto get from address. I want to show something in both addresses (no 404 error) and in more specific adrress have more values from it. I know that solution may be to write to rules(1 for long address and 1 for short), but for future it will be great to have one rule.
I am doing this for web where i have normal cms pages (short adrress) and blog, where i need more specific adrress.
Hope now its clearer, sorry english is my second language.

Comment: Okay, now I think I get the picture - what you're trying to do with the capture groups and why all the repetition. Give me a few minutes...